# Simulation software for electrons scattering effects in materials

Tags: electrons, resource-recommendations, scattering, software, microscopy

I am currently trying to find a software where I can simulate the effects of an electron beam hitting different materials of certain thicknesses, and get information such as how many backscatter, how many get stopped in the material and so on. Any tips?

Comment: Have not used it personally, but [GEANT4](https://geant4.web.cern.ch/) should be able to those these kind of things.